# Zustand with App router Next.js 13.4.12 Server page with local storage

Tags: javascript, next.js, zustand

I have a a zustand store like below

```
import create from "zustand";
import { persist } from "zustand/middleware";

const useProjectStore = create(
  persist(
    (set) => ({
      selectedProject: null,
      setSelectedProject: (project) => set({ selectedProject: project }),
    }),
    {
      name: "food-storage", // name of the item in the storage (must be unique)
      // (optional) by default, 'localStorage' is used
    }
  )
);

export default useProjectStore;
```

I want to use it in this page where I will get the state from the store of the current set project and then I will use the project ID from the state to update the prisma query with the current state projectID  -

```
import { prisma } from "@/lib/prismaDb";
import ImageList from "@/app/dashboard/components/imageList";
import ImageTable from "@/app/dashboard/components/imageTable";
import useProjectStore from "@/stores/currentProject-store";
import useServerStore from "@/stores/useServerStore";

const imagesPage = async () => {
  const useProjectStore = useServerStore((state) => state.useProjectStore);
  console.log("useProjectStore", useProjectStore);
  const imageList = await prisma.facebookImage.findMany({
    where: {
      projectId: "f2b78a6f-160f-4b2c-9cd5-b98c2f04d0d0",
    },
  });

  console.log("imageList2222");

  console.log("superaman", imageList);
  return (
    <div>
      <ImageTable imageList={imageList} />
      {/* <ImageList imageList={imageList} /> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default imagesPage;
```

The problem Im getting is the local storage cannot be accessed from the server. Is there anyway I can do this ?

I tried this - https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/integrations/persisting-store-data#usage-in-next.js from the zustand docs however when I do this im getting an error saying the hooks cannot be used on the server side.

Any questions I would be happy to answer
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component and put "use client" at top, for it to become a client component. Because hook are only available on client components. or you can made your imagePage a client page by putting "use client" at the top of the page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).